# AAPT2 error: check logs for details: unknown element <action> found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest, build.gradle

Here's my `debug\AndroidManifest.xml`

Getting so many errors like

> Element action is not allowed here.
>       Element category is not allowed here.
>       Attribute android:versionCode is not allowed here.
>       Attribute android:versionName is not allowed here.
>       Attribute android:theme is not allowed here. and so many.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.company.sqh.adio"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:debuggable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo_remaking2"
            android:label="@string/label"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.MainActivity"
                android:icon="@drawable/logo_remaking2" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.registraion_form" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.registraion_form" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.contact_us" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.contact_us" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.about_us" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.about_us" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.ProfileActivity" />

            <action android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.ProfileActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.EmplyReg" />
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.SubCategory" />
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.User_Profile" />
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.Emp_list" />
            <activity android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.Forgot_Pass" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.VERSION"
                android:value="26.1.0" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
                android:exported="false"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
                android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Please check this [image: screenshot]

Comment: Add error Messages as text not as link to dropbox

Comment: Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: @Jens i Thought it would be more easier to understand the problem using screen-shot  because there is so many error massage.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Sure, But which one? Debug\AndroidManifest.xml or main\AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: one in your screenshot.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I have updated it in my question please check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 Manifest Error: unknown element <action> found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948498/android-studio-3-0-manifest-error-unknown-element-action-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AndroidManifest.xml:15: error: unknown element  found.

**You have a misplaced tag.**

> To improve incremental resource processing, Android plugin 3.0.0 **enables AAPT2 by default.**
>   In previous versions of AAPT, **elements nested in incorrect nodes in the Android manifest are either ignored** or result in a warning.
>   **To resolve the issue, make sure your manifest elements are nested correctly. For more information, read [Manifest file structure](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct).**

You have to modify your Manifest:

```
 <action android:name="com.company.sqh.adio.ProfileActivity" />         
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

They should be included inside an `<activity>` tag.

You can read [more here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#aapt2).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i've gotten this error (**AAPT2**) building the apk with **Cordova** build command, turns out it was a problem caused by the path to ./gradle user dependencies.
The problem was the path itself where my username had special characters. Gradle was reading "?" instead of "Á", creating a new user solved the problem.

OS: Windows 10