# AAPT: error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found in <manifest><application> after upgrading to android 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.4 and I have the first error

My manifest in app/srs/main/AndroidManifest.xml is. Pls Help me cuz i cant fix it.What Should i Do Need experts

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.whatsapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WhatsApp" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.whatsapp.SigninActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.whatsapp.SignUp_activity" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.whatsapp.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
````

```

Comment: That `<intent-filter>` belongs inside an `<activity>` element, not the `<application>` element. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46948498

Answer (score 3):

The `<intent-filter>` should be inside `<activity>` or `<receiver>` or `<service>` tags

Example:

```
<receiver android:name=".SomeBootReceiverClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```